# How can I fix this strange text in Blue J

Tags: java, bluej

I downloaded the program from the official website, had a normal installation, and literally without move anything, I got this strange language text, I tried to change language in preferences trying to guess every option because I don't understand anything, and I didn't get any change, I don't know what it's due to, I'm from Mexico, I speak Spanish and everything on my laptop is either in Spanish or English.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me since I will use this program this semester at my university but the numbers and letters in the interface are too different to keep up with the teacher.

Thanks in advance.

I will attach the images.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQbEW.png)

I tried like 4 versions and trying in another website but it didnt work.

My O.S. is Windows 10

Comment: Your image is not clear!

Comment: What platform are you on? Is it Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I already solved this problem, I had to put

```
.root {

   -fx-font-family: “Source Sans Pro";

}
```

on every CSS file in `lib\stylesheets` folder.

If you want any help with this one-in-a-million chance problem, feel free to send me a message :)